# What is the statisitical weight of a system?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I am currently reading up on statistical mechanics and was wondering what is the statistical weight of a system? My understanding is that you have a deck of cards and there are 4 queens to the deck, then this mean that queen have a statistical weight of 4, and drawing the queen from the deck would be like saying that the queen is a micostate of the system of a deck which is a macrostate.

But relating that to a system of particles is where im confusing my self a bit. I can seem to visualise what going on as such. I keep getting in a muddle with how many macro states to a system and microstaes with in a system of macrostates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Systems have no "statistical weights". These are, in fact, a property of their *microstates*. Let's say that a system is identified by a certain number of degrees of freedom (positions, for example). A given microstate is a microscopic configuration where these degrees of freedom take some specific value. In the case of particles inside a box, a microstate would be determined by the exact positions of all the particles. Therefore, in order to specify in which microstate the system is, we have to provide the whole set of particle positions (and momenta in the case of a thermodynamic system).

If we are dealing with macroscopic systems (such as a gas), the number of degrees of freedom is huge and thus microstates cannot really be specified. Luckily for us, it turns out that the *macroscopic* state (or macrostate) of these systems can be fully specified by a very limited set of quantities (density, pressure, temperature, *etc.*).

As you can imagine, the number of microstates is much bigger than the number of macrostates, meaning that there are many microstates that correspond to a specific macrostate. However, generally speaking a specific microstate does not *belong* to a specific macrostate. Rather, given a macrostate, there is a certain probability that the system is in a specific microstate. This probability is what we call the *statistical weight* of such microstate. **Nota Bene:** a microstate possesses a statistical weight *relative to a specific macrostate* and not by its own.

If we go back to your deck of cards, we can make up a better analogy:

- we define as a microstate a hand of 2 randomly-drawn card
- a macrostate is defined by a quantity $A$ which is just the average over the values of a hand. Since here we are making up the rules, let's say that the ace takes the value of 1 and the Jacks, Queens and Kings are all just [Face cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Face_card) that have a value of 11.

Note that in this specific case a microstate is associated to one (and one only) macrostate.

Let us choose the particular macrostate $A = 13$. The following hands (that is, microstates) are all representative microscopic configurations of the system associated to this macrostate:

- 7 - 6
- 5 - 8
- Face - 2
- 2 - Face

Of course there are many others. Since we are drawing the cards randomly, each of these microstates occur with a different probability. Since we have grouped all the face cards together, the probability of drawing a card with a value of 11 is $12/52$, whereas the probability of drawing a card with any other value is $4/52$. Since the *statistical weight* of a microstate is just its probability of occurring given a specific macrostate, we can now compute this value for each hand. For instance, for the case of $A = 13$, the probability of a 6-7 microstate is $\left(\frac{4}{52}\right)^2$, that of a Face - 2 is $\frac{4}{52}\frac{12}{52}$ and that of a 2 - 2 is zero, since the latter cannot occur when $A = 13$ (that is, for the macrostate we are considering).